# why require_once just return true, not the array I define;

Tags: php, laravel

I was require a file just define a array. like:

```
$config = require_once base_path().'/config/webchat.php';
var_dump($config);
exit();
```

and the webchat.php is just define a array like :

```
$path = __DIR__.'/../storage/webchat_tmp/';

return [
    'path'     => $path,
    /*
     * swoole 配置项（执行主动发消息命令必须要开启）
     */
    'swoole'  => [
        'status' => false,
        'ip'     => '127.0.0.1',
        'port'   => '8866',
    ]
];
```

the $config was result in a boolean true, not the array. could someone tell me why , thanks a lot . and the path is right. because when I set exit() in the webchat.php . it was exit right;

Answer (score 0):

`require_once` return true if file successfully included. But it doesn't return array. So you should write following code to have `$config` array in other file. In the other words you add lines of `webchat.php` in other file by `require_once` it:

```
require_once base_path().'/config/webchat.php';
var_dump($config);
exit();
```

And

```
$path = __DIR__.'/../storage/webchat_tmp/';

$config = [
    'path'     => $path,
    /*
     * swoole 配置项（执行主动发消息命令必须要开启）
     */
    'swoole'  => [
        'status' => false,
        'ip'     => '127.0.0.1',
        'port'   => '8866',
    ]
];
```

When execute the php code, it seems like this:

```
$path = __DIR__.'/../storage/webchat_tmp/';

$config = [
    'path'     => $path,
    /*
     * swoole 配置项（执行主动发消息命令必须要开启）
     */
    'swoole'  => [
        'status' => false,
        'ip'     => '127.0.0.1',
        'port'   => '8866',
    ]
];

var_dump($config);
exit();
```